# When writing my own R package, I can't seem to get other packages to import correctly

Tags: r, import, namespaces, roxygen

Alright, first attempt at writing an R package and I'm stuck. Here's how I create the package:

```
package.skeleton("pkg",code_files=some.filenames)
roxygenize("okg")
```

I'm using roxygen2 and have the following imports in my "pkg-package.R" file:

```
@import data.table zoo lubridate
```

From a terminal, I then run:

```
R CMD build pkg
R CMD check pkg
R CMD install pkg
```

During the check phase, I get the following warnings:

> ** preparing package for lazy loading
>   Warning: replacing previous import ‘hour’ when loading ‘lubridate’
>   Warning: replacing previous import ‘mday’ when loading ‘lubridate’
>   Warning: replacing previous import ‘month’ when loading ‘lubridate’
>   Warning: replacing previous import ‘wday’ when loading ‘lubridate’
>   Warning: replacing previous import ‘week’ when loading ‘lubridate'
>   Warning: replacing previous import ‘yday’ when loading ‘lubridate’
>   Warning: replacing previous import ‘year’ when loading ‘lubridate’
>   ** help
>   *** installing help indices
>   ** building package indices ...
>   ** testing if installed package can be loaded
>   Warning messages:
>   1: replacing previous import ‘hour’ when loading ‘lubridate’
>   2: replacing previous import ‘mday’ when loading ‘lubridate’
>   3: replacing previous import ‘month’ when loading ‘lubridate’
>   4: replacing previous import ‘wday’ when loading ‘lubridate’
>   5: replacing previous import ‘week’ when loading ‘lubridate’
>   6: replacing previous import ‘yday’ when loading ‘lubridate’
>   7: replacing previous import ‘year’ when loading ‘lubridate’

I'm really not sure what to make of those, but they seem like typical warnings from overwriting stuff in namespace.  In any case, I am able to install the package, but here's what happens when I try to use it:

> > library(pkg)
> >     Overriding + and - methods for POSIXt, Date and difftime
> >     Warning messages:
> >     1: replacing previous import ‘hour’ when loading ‘lubridate’
> >     2: replacing previous import ‘mday’ when loading ‘lubridate’
> >     3: replacing previous import ‘month’ when loading ‘lubridate’
> >     4: replacing previous import ‘wday’ when loading ‘lubridate’
> >     5: replacing previous import ‘week’ when loading ‘lubridate’
> >     6: replacing previous import ‘yday’ when loading ‘lubridate’
> >     7: replacing previous import ‘year’ when loading ‘lubridate’
> >     d <- my.function(arg1, arg2)
> >     Error in MATCH(x, x) : could not find function "MATCH"

Using traceback(), I found out that this is being generating during a call to merge.zoo().  So I tried loading zoo by hand during my R session and voila, then the function works correctly without the error message.

I have tried changing the ordering of the imports by hand in both the "pkg-package.R" file, as well as in NAMESPACE.  Based on something I found elsewhere, I have not added any Imports or Depends to DESCRIPTION, however.  Help?

Comment: I'd recommend putting these packages into your `Depends` in the `DESCRIPTION`.

Answer (score 43):

The warnings are because data.table and lubridate both define a symbol `hour`, etc; see `data.table::hour` and `lubridate::hour`. You could avoid this by importing just the functions from lubridate / data.table that you want, rather than the whole package; a standard NAMESPACE file would contain

```
importFrom(lubridate, hour)
```

for instance. In roxygen2 you would use the tag:

```
@importFrom lubridate hour
```

The MATCH problem is probably because `merge` is dispatching incorrectly, probably because zoo should have in its name space `S3method(merge, zoo)` rather than `export(merge.zoo)`, as described in Writing R Extensions, 1.6.2. The solution here is to contact the maintainer of `zoo`, `packageDescription('zoo')$Maintainer` (the maintainer is sufficiently versed in R that I feel like I've mis-diagnosed...).

Comment: This is a useful answer, but just a follow up. So if I just import a single function like "hour," do I also need to import all of its internal or potentially private functions as well? Or will `importFrom` know to import any private functions or internal dependencies?

Comment: @krishnab functions look for the symbols they use first in their own environment, then in the environment in which the function was defined, so data.table functions that data.table::hour uses will be found automatically.

Comment: What happens when you need to use import for multiple packages to have access to specific object classes and they have name conflicts? I am running into to this with spatstat and raster (area, rotate, shift). I cannot use importFrom because I am using numerous functions from both and need the package classes. Is there a way to mask out the three raster functions that conflict with spatstat? I should note that just using depends in DESCRIPTION is not working.

Comment: You can also use import except: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51899220/import-all-the-functions-of-a-package-except-one-when-building-a-package

Answer (score 1):

As a temporary workaround for the MATCH error, I've had success listing the `zoo` package under the `Depends:` section of the package's `DESCRIPTION` file.