# setOldClass("xts") causing problems in a custom R package

Tags: r, package, xts, quantmod

I wrote an R package which contains an S4 class which uses `xts` objects.  It's my understanding that I need to include the line

```
setOldClass("xts")
stock.returns <- setClass(
    Class = "stock.returns",
    slots = c(xts_returns = "xts", timeframe = "timeframe", currency = "character"),
    prototype = prototype(xts_returns = xts::xts(, order.by = c(lubridate::today())), timeframe = timeframe(), currency = "Local")
)
```

at the top of my class definition script.  Problems occur when I use my package to create my object.  It works, but I *occasionally* get this warning repeated several times:

```
Found more than one class "xts" in cache; using the first, from namespace 'quantmod'
```

**How can I force my class to use the correct `xts` package instead of defaulting to the `quantmod` package?**  Failing this, how do I at least stop the warnings?

I note this conversation between Hadley Wickham and another, on the same topic:  http://r.789695.n4.nabble.com/setOldClass-quot-xts-quot-td4714332.html.  It went nowhere.

**EDIT:** My NAMESPACE file is

```
# Generated by roxygen2: do not edit by hand

export("%>%")
export(EOMonth)
export(EOWeek)
export(VaR.cree)
export(date_to_sql_string)
export(df_to_xts)
export(ewma)
export(factor_model_maker)
export(flatten_xts)
export(get_USD_fx)
export(get_benchmark_index)
export(get_benchmark_xts_returns)
export(get_bond_index)
export(get_currency_index)
export(get_end_date)
export(get_financial_history)
export(get_financial_history_and_make_it_monthly)
export(get_frequency)
export(get_fund_performance)
export(get_fx_USD_history)
export(get_fx_cross)
export(get_index_snapshot)
export(get_metrics_history)
export(get_portfolio)
export(get_price_history)
export(get_shock_results)
export(get_shock_results.yield_version)
export(get_spc_xts_raw_total_returns)
export(get_spc_xts_returns)
export(get_start_date)
export(get_table_from_sql_CISMPRDSVR)
export(get_test_date)
export(get_ticker_xts_return_index)
export(get_ticker_xts_t_data_fs_eps)
export(get_watchlist)
export(get_yield_index)
export(market_capture_ratio)
export(previous_business_date_if_weekend)
export(price_plot)
export(rel_plot)
export(return_over_horizon)
export(rolling_correlation)
export(run_sql_in_CISMPRDSVR)
export(scenario_analysis)
export(show_regression)
export(single_experiment_summary)
export(stock.returns)
export(timeframe)
export(update_fund_performance_from_spreadsheet)
export(write.zoo)
export(xts_add_average_series)
export(xts_price_from_returns)
export(xts_returns)
exportClasses(timeframe)
```

And my DESCRIPTION file is:

```
Package: cree
Title: CI Risk Engine, Eh?
Version: 0.0.0.9000
Authors@R: person("Mr", "lebelinoz", email = "lebelinoz@mycompany.com", role = c("aut", "cre"))
Description: All the in-house risk tools built in R.
Depends: R (>= 3.3.1)
License: Proprietary. Do not distribute outside My Company Limited.
Encoding: UTF-8
LazyData: true
RoxygenNote: 6.0.1
Imports:
    tidyverse,
    lubridate,
    quantmod,
    xts,
    zoo,
    RODBC,
    PerformanceAnalytics
Collate: 
    'Functions.R'
    'Sql_Wrapper.R'
    'StockPlot.R'
    'VaR.cree.R'
    'ewma.R'
    'timeframe.R'
    'stock.returns.R'
    'factor_model_maker.R'
    'get_benchmark_index.R'
    'get_bond_index.R'
    'get_currency_index.R'
    'get_financial_history.R'
    'get_fx_.R'
    'get_metrics_history.R'
    'get_portfolio.R'
    'get_price_history.R'
    'get_shock_results.R'
    'get_shock_results.yield_version.R'
    'get_yield_index.R'
    'market_capture_ratio.R'
    'return_over_horizon.R'
    'scenario_analysis.R'
    'show_regression.R'
    'show_regression_between_xts.R'
    'single_experiment_summary.R'
    'update_fund_performance_from_spreadsheet.R'
```

Comment: Did you try using the `::` operator? Eg: `xts::` to avoid conflicts?

Comment: @ar7 Yes I have, but it causes compilation errors.  I've added my sample class to help clarify my question.

Comment: Your NAMESPACE and DESCRIPTION files are also relevant. Is your package source code publicly available?

Comment: @JoshuaUlrich No, it's for work.

Comment: Then you need to provide your NAMESPACE and DESCRIPTION files.

Comment: @JoshuaUlrich This has been done.  Not that I know anything about NAMESPACE files:  mine is generated by the `roxygen2` package.

Comment: This [Bioconductor-devel thread](https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/bioc-devel/2016-April/009149.html) discusses a similar issue.  I checked the relevant R sources and it appears some of the patches discussed in the thread are in the current release of R.  What version of R are you using?

Comment: @JoshuaUlrich I justed realised I'm on version 3.3.1.  I've upgraded to 3.4.0, now:  we'll see if that makes my problem go away.

Comment: @JoshuaUlrich It didn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that your NAMESPACE file does not include any imports. Specifying Imports in the DESCRIPTION file only indicates that your package imports stuff from the listed packages. You must also explicitly import specific functions in the NAMESPACE file.

Using a skeleton package, I can replicate the messages using the following commands:

```
library(quantmod)
stock_returns = anRpackage::stock.returns()@xts_returns
economic.factor.model <- setClass("economic.factor.model",
    slots = c(stock_returns = "xts", factor_premiums = "xts"))
```

But I don't get any messages if I import quantmod, xts, and zoo. My package contains only the following files:

```
> ls -l anRpackage/*
-rw-rw-r-- 1 josh josh  311 Jun 21 05:35 anRpackage/DESCRIPTION
-rw-rw-r-- 1 josh josh   75 Jun 21 05:55 anRpackage/NAMESPACE

anRpackage/man:
total 4
-rw-rw-r-- 1 josh josh 713 Jun 21 05:38 anRpackage-package.Rd

anRpackage/R:
total 4
-rw-rw-r-- 1 josh josh 364 Jun 21 05:40 file.R
```

The contents of DESCRIPTION are:

```
Package: anRpackage
Type: Package
Title: What the package does (short line)
Version: 1.0
Date: 2017-06-21
Author: Who wrote it
Maintainer: Who to complain to <yourfault@somewhere.net>
Description: More about what it does (maybe more than one line)
License: What license is it under?
Imports: quantmod, xts, zoo
```

The contents of NAMESPACE are below. Note that I simply import everything from the 3 listed packages for testing purposes. It's better practice to selectively import only the functions you use. If you have no `import()` commands in your NAMESPACE file, you can use `R CMD check` to tell you what functions need to be imported from each package.

Lesson learned: `R CMD check` is useful even if you don't intend to submit your package to CRAN. ;-)

```
exportPattern("^[[:alpha:]]+")
import(quantmod)
import(xts)
import(zoo)
```

The contents of R/file.R are:

```
setOldClass("xts")
stock.returns <- setClass(
    Class = "stock.returns",
    slots = c(xts_returns = "xts",
              timeframe = "character",
              currency = "character"),
    prototype = prototype(xts_returns = xts::xts(, order.by = Sys.Date()),
                          timeframe = "timeframe()",
                          currency = "Local")
)
```

And the contents of man/anRpackage-package.Rd are:

```
\name{anRpackage-package}
\alias{anRpackage-package}
\alias{anRpackage}
\docType{package}
\title{
\packageTitle{anRpackage}
}
\description{
\packageDescription{anRpackage}
}
\details{

The DESCRIPTION file:
\packageDESCRIPTION{anRpackage}
\packageIndices{anRpackage}
~~ An overview of how to use the package, including the most important ~~
~~ functions ~~
}
\author{
\packageAuthor{anRpackage}

Maintainer: \packageMaintainer{anRpackage}
}
\references{
~~ Literature or other references for background information ~~
}
\keyword{ package }
\seealso{
~~ Optional links to other man pages, e.g. ~~
~~ \code{\link[<pkg>:<pkg>-package]{<pkg>}} ~~
}
\examples{
#~~ simple examples of the most important functions ~~
}
```

Comment: Thanks.  Is there a `roxygen2` way of modifying NAMESPACE?  The first line of my NAMESPACE file is `# Generated by roxygen2: do not edit by hand`

Comment: I think I found the answer.  I need to use `@import` and `@importFrom` tags in my `roxygen2` comments, as discussed in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10325231/when-writing-my-own-r-package-i-cant-seem-to-get-other-packages-to-import-corr/10325867#10325867

Comment: @lebelinoz: yes, and I would encourage you to use `@importFrom` instead of pulling in an entire package.