# import all the functions of a package except one when building a package

Tags: r, import, dependencies, r-package

I'm building an R package (**mypackage**) that imports data.table and another package (let's call it **myotherpackage**).

`Imports: data.table, myotherpackage` is in the DESCRIPTION file of **mypackage**.

**myotherpackage** imports dplyr, which has several functions named like the data.table functions, so I get warnings like this everytime I load **mypackage**:

`Warning: replacing previous import ‘data.table::first’ by ‘dplyr::first’ when loading ‘mypackage’`

Is there a way to import all the functions of data.table except "first" for example? I'd then use data.table::first in the code if I need to use it.
Or is there a better way to handle it? I'm trying to avoid the warning every time someones imports the package. Thank you!

Comment: Use `importFrom(my other package, function)` directives in your NAMESPACE rather than importing all functions from the package.

Comment: Thanks @Thomas. I was hoping that there would be an alternative to specifying every data.table function I want to import (which is pretty much all of them). Looks like I'm out of luck.

Comment: You can also specify `import(data.table, except=c(foo))`. See https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-devel/R-exts.html#Specifying-imports-and-exports. I don't know if you can get that using roxygen markup, though.

Comment: Yes! @Thomas, it worked! 
I had to use the following syntax in the function description (instead of `#' @import data.table`): 
`#' @rawNamespace import(data.table, except = first)`
Do you wanna answer the question so I can give you credit?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

The NAMESPACE file is somewhat flexible here, as described in [Writing R Extensions](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-devel/R-exts.html#Specifying-imports-and-exports).

The two main import directives are:

```
import(PACKAGE)
```

which imports all objects in the namespace into your package. The second option is to do specific imports using:

```
importFrom(PACKAGE, foo)
```

which gives you access to `foo()` without needing the fully qualified reference `PACKAGE::foo()`.

But these aren't the only two options. You can also use the `except` argument to exclude just a handful of imports:

```
import(PACKAGE, except=c(foo,bar))
```

which gives you everything from PACKAGE's namespace but `foo()` and `bar()`. This is useful - as in your case - for avoiding conflicts.

For roxygen, great catch on figuring out that you can do:

```
#' @rawNamespace import(PACKAGE, except = foo)
```

to pass a raw NAMESPACE directive through roxygen.